# HCP Consul with Spring Cloud Consul Discovery - Failing to connect to HCP Consul

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul

I try to connect my spring application to the HCP Consul Discovery Service.

Running consul locally in dev mode works well.

```
consul agent -dev
```

application.yml file looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

However, when I try to connect to HCP Consul I get:

```
[catalogWatchTaskScheduler-1] org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulCatalogWatch: Error watching Consul CatalogServices
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to HOST:8500 [HOST/IP] failed: Connect timed out
```

This is the configuration I use:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: HCP_HOST
      port: 8500
      scheme: https
```

HCP Consul is available to public connections.
I manage to see the members using the CLI command

```
consul members
```

This is the dependency I use in the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What do I miss in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port 8501 with HTTPS scheme solves this issue.

See [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/install/ports) the ports used for each protocol. HTTPS seems to be disabled by default.